# Can't convert accents and foreign characters in R (Text Mining)

Tags: r, text-mining

Been trying to convert some tweets with the text mining package in R. Collected the tweets data and when transforming them into a Corpus and then a Data Frame all accents are lost and transformed into random characters. Searched a lot and nobody seem to answer. I need to convert them to portuguese.

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweetsCR.df$text))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation) 
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))  #??
myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, function(myCorpus) iconv(enc2utf8(myCorpus), sub     = "byte"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
```

Tried it on IBM workbench and it worked with accents. Seems that it is a system problem. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: How exactly do your tweets look like before you process them? And how exactly should they look like afterwards? Can you please provide a short example?

Comment: The tweets are normal. Showing accents, when converting to Corpus they mess up.

Comment: "Normal" for you might be "abnormal" for us. Furthermore, you are repeatedly assigning to the same name so you have no idea which of thise functions is mangling your data. Do some better debugging. If still not clear what is happening then edit the code to include a proper `library` call and  post at least enough items using `dput` so that experiments can be done.